# AngularJS spring security login/logout with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, cors, angularjs-http, spring-rest

Problem Statement: My UI app is running on 9000 port(grunt project) and my server side spring boot project running on 8421 port. I am able to hit all the URL's from my UI app except login and logout. Please let me know how can I configure spring security login and logout with CORS.

App.js

```
  $scope.login = function() {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8421/login', $.param($scope.credentials), {
          headers : {
            'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        }).success(function() {
          console.log('login success');
          });
        }).error(function() {
          console.log('login error');
        });
      };
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(new SimpleCORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
        .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")        
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)       
        .and().formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .and().formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)         
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }

@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

SimpleCORSFilter.java

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

login.html

```
<form>
<div class="rb-form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.username" placeholder="enter your username" required>
        </div>

        <!-- PASSWORD -->
        <div class="rb-form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="enter your password" required>        
        </div>

        <div class="rb-form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Login</button>        
        </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Network log

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8421
Request URL:http://localhost:8421/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 17 Nov 2015 04:01:57 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=D22C05E81D4FC86EA32BD6545F2B37FF; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:31
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:8421
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/src/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Keep it simple and run the frontend within your spring web server and use the same port and protocol. If you really really really need to use CORS please post the network logs. Specially the request to the login URI (methods: OPTION and POST)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question with network log for login. Please take a look.

Comment: Yes, CORS is necessary as we are building same enterprise application for different clients. So we need to decouple all the things.

Comment: Are you using tomcat with web.xml config?

Comment: I"m confused - your log says that the POST request Request to **http://localhost:8421/login** returned with Status Code:`200 OK`. What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

As far as CORS issue is concerned, please add `authorization` and `client-security-token` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers header` as below.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
```

This should work properly if your CORS filter is correctly configured!

For using AJAX based login in spring security, you might want to follow slightly different approach. This is explained here:

- [Spring security 3 Ajax login – accessing protected resources](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/spring-security-3-ajax-login-accessing.html)
- [Implementing Ajax Authentication](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery)

Hope it helps, feel free to comment for any issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm done this issue on the AngularJS and Spring application. It's quite simple. Just add the filter

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
         res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
         chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }        
    }
}
```

From the post [angularjs spring cross-origin request blocked](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html)